# Scraping table data using Scrapy (python)

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I am working on a project and it involves scraping data from a website using Scrapy.
Earlier we were using Selenium but now we have to use Scrapy.
I don't have any knowledge on Scrapy but learning it right now.
One of the challenges  is to scrap the data from a website, the data is structured in tables and though there are links to download such data, it's not working in my case.

Below is the structure of the tables
[html structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN2tY.png)

All my data is under tbody and each having tr

The pseudo code which I have written so far is:

```
def parse_products(self, response):
    rows=response.xpath('//*[@id="records_table"]/tbody/')
    for i in rows:
      item = table_item()
      item['company'] = i.xpath('td[1]//text()').extract_first()
      item['naic'] = i.xpath('td[2]//text()').extract_first()
      yield item
```

Am I accessing the table body correctly with the xpath?
Not sure if the xpath i specified is correct or not

Comment: What is your actual question? It's unclear what we should be helping with

Comment: is my code correct?
when i am trying to run 'rows=response.xpath('//*[@id="records_table"]/tbody/')'
on scapy shell, i am getting an empty list

Comment: If you are scrapping  from only one website then I would recommend you use beautiful soup and not scrappy

Comment: Path to `tr` then `td`, like `item['company'] = i.xpath('/tr[1]/td//text()').extract_first()`

Comment: `rows` point to table. You should identify table then `rows = table.xpath('tr')` and _then_ iterate through rows for forming your entries.

Answer (score 0):

Better to say:

```
def parse_products(self, response):
    for row in response.css('table#records_table tr'):
      item = table_item()
      item['company'] = row.xpath('.//td[1]/text()').get()
      item['naic'] = row.xpath('.//td[2]/text()').get()
      yield item
```

Here you will be iterating by rows of table and then taking data of cells.